# Apigee is not showing analytic numbers

Tags: apigee

When initially evaluating Apigee it was showing pretty up-to-date analytic numbers on the API Proxy dashboard. Now that we're doing a trial run in production (and hitting it hard), the dashboard shows all zeros.

When I set up traces for the proxies, there is definitely traffic coming through.

Please help! Thanks! Organization:verba

Answer (score 1):

Two things -- first, make sure you're looking at the right environment. The dashboard reports have a dropdown menu in the upper right hand corner for prod or test.  By default your work gets deployed to"test" (yourorg-test.apigee.net) but it seems to switch sometimes from test to prod without specifically being set.

The other thing is that Analytics often take longer to get processed and show up in the free Developer product (which I assume you're using to evaluate Apigee).  It's a multi-tenant environment which a huge amount of data that's being digested before being available in the reports.

Hope that helps

Comment: I've only set up test environments. Switching to prod doesn't do anything, and none of my proxies have prod environments created. I'm using the test proxy endpoints. And the analytics, once working, have not worked for several days now. Pretty discouraging.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the inconvenience. We have fixed the issue. Would you please check the reports and let us know if the reports are generated.